# Error when using loaded Keras classifier with custom metrics function

Tags: python, keras

I have a keras model, which uses custom function for metrics:

`model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy', roc_auc])`

The function works fine and model behaves as expected. However, when saving the model via `model.save()` and then loading it via `model.load_model()`, I get `ValueError: Unknown metric function:roc_auc` when running following code: `model.predict(X)`. Interestingly this error does not appear when I run the same command again, through command shell, it only occurs during first run. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean `keras.models.load_model(path)`? It sounds very strange to have `model.load_model()`.

You are probably missing the argument `custom_objects = {'roc_auc': roc_auc}` in `load_model`. Keras cannot create a model if it doesn't know what `roc_auc` means.

Comment: Yes, I meant model with path of course. Your solution worked, I was missing `custom_objects` parameter. Still confused why it did not give error when running same thing for second time